# Android deep linking with navigation graph bug

Tags: android, deep-linking, android-navigation-graph

For instance when I have:

```
   <fragment
      ...
        <deepLink
            ...
            app:uri="https://www.google.com/" /> // forward slash at the end works
    </fragment>
```

While the below code does not:

```
   <fragment
      ...
        <deepLink
            app:uri="https://www.google.com" /> // This does not
    </fragment>
```

I also have to append a forward slash at the end when invoking the intent via terminal:

```
`adb shell am start https://www.google.com` (Does not show app in list of options)

`adb shell am start https://www.google.com/` (Shows app in list of options)
```